# How do I loop an embedded Facebook video?

Tags: javascript, facebook, loops, video

I'm trying to embed a Facebook video. I've tried to use the following JavaScript to force it loop:

```
$("#u_0_5").bind('ended', function() {
   this.play();
});
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help me make this video loop?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me make this video loop?

That is currently not possible.

There is no JavaScript API for the Embedded Video Player plugin; and since the plugin renders as an iframe with content loaded from a different domain, you have no access to it with your own JavaScript code either (Same Origin Policy) - not even to attach any events to it.